# Java - Large String need to split with different field length

Tags: java

I'm new to Java and didn't find any exact solution for my scenario. I have a large string which is 1500 length.

For example : 
`String inData = "THISKALJSKAJFDSKJDKSJ KSJDLKJSFKD LSKJDFKSJ, ASA:..";`

I have a fixed format for these 1500 length. I have to split the string into 200+ fields based on each field fixed length. I found something like below.

`String firstFld = inData.substring(0, 2);`

`String secondFld = inData.substring(3, 10);`

`String thirdFld = inData.substring(11, 13);`

can anyone please suggest with better way of doing the split instead of declaring 200 string variables and store them there or loading them to a String Array ? I plan to to build an xml with all these fields after getting them.

I appreciate all your help!

Comment: use an `array` of length 200

Comment: You could split the string into an Array or List

Comment: What is the fixed format? Is it stored anywhere in your code?

Comment: Maybe try to learn the basics (arrays, collections etc.) before you start working with XML.

Comment: the fixed length is stored in a file. I understand I could add this to an array. But if there any other better options ? I updated the question to include the string array as an option.

Comment: Well, the array would be a 1000 times better option than what you have now, what's wrong with using that? Or a collection?

Answer (score 1):

Well, if it's two of the below, then this would work:

1. There's a pattern for the field lengths: like (0,2), (3, 10), (11,13), (14, 21) ...
2. You have a list of field lengths

In both cases it is pretty simple to solve what you want:

First Case: Pattern is 2 chars -> 7 chars starting with 2

```
String[] fields = new String[getNumberOfFields(1500)];
int curr = 0;
for(int i = 0 ; i < fields.length; i++) {
    if(i % 2 == 0) {
        fields[i] = inData.substring(curr, curr+7);
        curr+=8;
    } else {
        fields[i] = inData.substring(curr, curr+2);
        curr+=3;
    }
}
```

Second Case: You have a bunch of different field lenghts

```
int curr = 0;
String[] fields = new String[fieldLengths.length];
for(int i = 0; i < fieldLengths.length; i++) {
     fields[i] = inData.substring(curr, curr+fieldLengths[i]);
}
```

Comment: If the pattern is more complex though, I would implement it a different way, dependent on how complex and on what it was.